# Laravel Http::get not working on controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have the Http request in my controller:

```
    $url = url('/api/list-professional');

    $professionals = Http::get($url);
```

These two lines work perfectly fine when I use them in my phpUnit Tests,
But when I use them inside a controller it just gets a time out.

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that `php artisan serve` is a single-thread application. So when we use an HTTP client to request from it to itself, it basically just tries to finish the guzzle  HTTP client (as a client) first then comes to finish that request (as a server), which is impossible.

So create two ports using php artisan serve . One is for HTTP client and another port is to access from browser

for example if you have created port 8000 and 8001 then

```
$professionals = Http::get("http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/list-professional");
```

and use 8000 port to access from browser

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `Http::get` call in a try-catch block to capture and log any possible exceptions.

```
try {
    $professionals = Http::get($url);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Log the exception
    Log::error($e->getMessage());
}
```

You can also increase the timeout.

```
$professionals = Http::timeout(60)->get($url);
```

Comment: I still get a timeout,
my guess is that maybe localhost can't deal with multiple requests, so it gets in a loop where it cant answer the API call while the call that called the method hasn't been answered yet.
But I need someone with more understanding to confirm that this kind of thing happens.